# Replace part of a string using 0,1 instead of " "

Tags: java, android, string, replace, substring

```
    mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Everybody")) {
                PRIVACY = PRIVACY.replace(PRIVACY.substring(0, 1), "E");
                Log.d("TEXT", PRIVACY);
            } else if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Nobody")) {
                PRIVACY = PRIVACY.replace(PRIVACY.substring(0, 1), "N");
                Log.d("TEXT", PRIVACY);
            }
        }
    });
```

Privacy string = "E/E/N/N/E......../N

I have multiple Buttons for changing each Char

It's just a random Chars separated by "/"

So on click of the Toggle Button, I want to replace one of the Chars with either E or N but this above code I'm replacing everything like the result is either E/E/E/E/E.... or N/N/N/N/N...

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
PRIVACY = PRIVACY.replace(PRIVACY.substring(0, 1), "E")
```

is replacing inside `PRIVACY` every occurrence of whatever the 1st char is with "E",  
because the 1st parameter of the `replace()` method is the string to find.  
Do it like this:

```
mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Everybody")) {
            PRIVACY = "E" + PRIVACY.substring(1);
            Log.d("TEXT", PRIVACY);
        } else if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Nobody")) {
            PRIVACY = "N" + PRIVACY.substring(1);
            Log.d("TEXT", PRIVACY);
        }
    }
});
```

`PRIVACY.substring(1)` is the part of PRIVACY beginning from the 2nd char until its end.
*Edit*
If you want to replace the 5th char with say "A":

```
PRIVACY = PRIVACY.substring(0, 5) + "A" + PRIVACY.substring(6);
```

See more [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: what to do it i want to replace a middle char?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to replace a char at one position. One of them is the use of stringbuilder.

Example:

```
 mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Everybody")) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(PRIVACY[0]);
            stringbuilder.setCharAt(0, 'N'); //you can also use "N".charAt(0) instead of 'N'
            Log.d("TEXT", stringbuilder.toString());
        } else if (mSwitch.getText().equals("Nobody")) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(PRIVACY[0]);
            stringbuilder.setCharAt(0, 'E'); //you can also use "E".charAt(0) instead of 'E'
            Log.d("TEXT", stringbuilder.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: setCharAt not accepting string value when i put tostring method